# File is not Opening WinRAR Issue

Tags: winrar

1- I saved my image files in WinRAR in windows 8 about 6 years ago and protected them with WinRAR password ..

2- recently I changed desktop computer with windows 10 and connect my old hard drive with this new pc

3 though I have the correct password, the files are not opening and showing message quote: " Access is denied "

ANY ONE PLEASE HELP ..

Comment: Have you verified your user has the correct ACL permissions to access the file? I list both the GUI and CLI methods in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1724974/529800) answer, the only change you would make would be GUI: change _Read & Execute_ to _Full Control_ | CLI: change `RX` to `F`

Comment: Access denied usually does not refer to a password issue. Can you copy the archive to your local drive and extract from there instead? Does WinRAR have an archive checking tool or function you can use to see if the file is healthy or corrupt?